# modifying multiple tables in a database with the same changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I inherited a large database with many tables and related databases. They had used an identifying value of `VARCHAR(8)` this is used in different tables.

Now we want to make these improvements:

- modify this column to be of type `VARCHAR(20)`
- add a Unique ID that would be an `INT`.

How can I make a unique ID column and values for multiple tables and databases?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? And what is "IDENTIFYING" varchar value? Can give some examples of what's now and what you want?

Comment: For your Int-based Unique ID, can you not just use an `Identity` field on each table?

Comment: MSSQL modify column : use ALTER TABLE [table_name] ALTER COLUMN [column_name] varchar(20).  i am not sure if you want to add unique id column than can use identity. or add unique id to column size we just increase?

Comment: The IDENTIFYING value like ProductID varchar(8).  They used that as the primary key or foreign key.  Or sometimes just a joiner but no real sql link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run below query in your database and copy result of the query into new window to change data type. Similarly you can build query to add column.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' + t.TABLE_NAME + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + column_name + ' VARCHAR(20)' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
where c.COLUMN_NAME = 'Col1'
```

Comment: This is GREAT for making the change!!

Comment: Hi @MichaelKramer if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.